# Stuck in rehashing a Dictionary I Implemented using Hashtable in C

Tags: c, dictionary, hashtable

I have implemented this Hash table dictionary in c language. It is working fine without rehashing function.
Now,
I am trying to add a rehashing function it it which which allow to rehash it every time the load factor goes above 0.75. But it is not working properly. I need help in this regard..Tell me what i am doing wrong?

dict and list structures are here:

```
//List of bins
struct list {
    char *key;
    unsigned long hash;
    void *user_data;
    struct list *next;
};

//Main hash table Dictionary
struct dict {
    struct list **bins;
    unsigned int nbins;
    unsigned long int count;    /* for rehashing - for calculation load factor */
    void (*deleter)(void *user_data);
};
```

These are the steps that I documented for rehashing.

**1. Malloc() a new bin array that is twice as big**

`newNumberOfBin = D->nbins;`

**2. Move all list nodes to new array**

```
  -Get Stored hash 

  -Calulate new bin number of list node as
```

`int newBinNo = hash % newNumberOfBin;`

```
  -Move node to new bin
```

**3. Free old bin array**

**4. Update struct dict members**

```
  -bin will point to new_bins
 
  -nbins will be updated
```

The rehash function looks like this

```
static int dict_rehash(struct dict *D)
{

    int idx;
    int new_idx;

    unsigned int new_nbins; 
    struct list **new_bins;

    struct list *cur;

    //This block is just for debugging purpose..its working fine
    #if DEBUG
        /* print # of items in each bin */
    dict_debug_bin_fill(D);
    fprintf(stderr, "Rehashing...\n");
        /* pause for 3 seconds */
    sleep(3);
    #endif


    new_nbins = D->nbins*2; 
    new_bins = malloc(new_nbins*sizeof(*D->bins));

    for (idx=0; idx<D->nbins; idx++) {
        
        for(cur=D->bins[idx]; cur; cur=cur->next) {

               new_idx =  cur->hash%new_nbins;
               struct list *cur2 = new_bins[new_idx];

                    while(cur2 != NULL){
                        cur2=cur2->next;
                    }

                    cur2 = cur;
        }
    }

    free(D->bins);
    D->bins = new_bins;
    D->nbins = new_nbins;


    return 0;
}
```

I need help, where am I going wrong in this fuction?

Comment: You say that "it is not working properly", but *how* is it "nor working properly"? What is happening? What is supposed to happen? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Yes I have tried to debug it...Program automatically exits during rehashing for first time just after shifting first item of first bin to new_bin array.

Comment: "Just exiting" sounds like it's crashing. Have you tried to use an actual debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: `cur2 = cur` just changes the local variable, but it doesn't do anything to your linked lists. You want to remove a list node from the old table and insert it to the rehashed table. That means adjusting the list heads and the nodes' links.

Comment: Can you tell me little bit more on that how I can adjust the list heads and nodes in this perspective..!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you traverse the list in the new bin and then just re-assign a local variable, which doesn't do anything to your actual lists. When you delete the old bins and attach the new list of bins to your hash table, the nodes are still in the old bins and will be unaccessible.

Instead, for each old bin, while the bin's list is not empty, extract its head. Find the new bin and insert the extracted node at it's head. (The order of the items in the bins doesn't matter here.)

Extracting the first node is easy: Save the node and set the head to the next node. Inserting at the head of a list is easy, too: Set the node's link to the head, then set the head to the inserted node.

So:

```
static int dict_rehash(struct dict *D)
{
    unsigned int new_nbins = D->nbins * 2; 
    struct list **new_bins = malloc(new_nbins * sizeof(*D->bins));

    for (idx = 0; idx < D->nbins; idx++) {
        while (D->bins[idx]) {
            struct list *cur = D->bins[idx];
            int new_idx = cur->hash % new_nbins;
            
            // remove node from old list;
            
            D->bins[idx] = cur->next;
            
            // insert node at fromt of new list
            
            cur->next = new_bins[new_idx];
            new_bins[new_idx] = cur;
        }
    }

    free(D->bins);
    D->bins = new_bins;
    D->nbins = new_nbins;

    return 0;
}
```